# Prestashop 1.7 unable to display custom module

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm trying prestashop 1.7 and I have an issue with the creation of custom modules.
I have created a folder "mymodule" inside the "modules" folder, and, as it is indicate in the documentation I've created a simple mymodule.php file in it :

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
 exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'mymodule';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
    $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

    if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))      
      $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
  }
}

?>
```

Then I go on the administration page under "modules" -> "modules & services" on the "installed module" tab, but I can't find my module...

What error am I doing?

Thanks

Xavier

Comment: if you haven't installed the module it won't show in the installed module tab. you should look for it in the first tab. also, don't forget to add the install and uninstall function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your steps are all right.
To make a reminder, to create a 'custom' module we should do:

1. Create a folder in modules folder, e.g. named `mycustommodule`
2. Create a php file named like the folder, e.g. `mycustommodule.php`
3. Then the "bootstrap" class (and construct) should be like this:

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class MyCustomModule extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'mycustommodule'; /* This is the 'technic' name, this should equal to filename (mycustommodule.php) and the folder name */
        $this->tab = 'module type category'; /* administration, front_office_features, etc */
        $this->version = '1.0.0'; /* Your module version */
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname'; /* I guess it was clear */
        $this->need_instance = 0; /* If your module need an instance without installation */
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); /* Your compatibility with prestashop(s) version */
        $this->bootstrap = true; /* Since 1.6 the backoffice implements the twitter bootstrap */

        parent::__construct(); /* I need to explain that? */

        $this->displayName = $this->l('My module'); /* This is the name that merchant see */
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.'); /* A short description of functionality of this module */

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?'); /* This is a popup message before the uninstalling of the module */
    }
}
?>
```

Then for prestashop 1.7.x.x you have to go in `Modules` and in the `Selection` tab click on 'Categories' and find your module (remember the $this->tab snippet?)

[image: Categories menu]

otherwise you can find it by searching:

[image: Search input]

Comment: @Konrad I don't think it has changed too much, are you followed the steps?

Answer (score 5):

Today I encountered the same problem in Prestashop 1.7.6.1. Found 2 solutions to the problem:

1. Zip your module and upload it using Prestashop backoffice. Not good if for example you use git to upload changes. So I keep searching, and found solution no 2
2. If you create a custom module it appears in Module -> Catalog not in Modules -> Modules & Services tab... Very strange and counter intuitive behavior. After you install this module everything works as expected.

Comment: This is the only right answer for Prestashop 1.7.x , in 1.6 backoffice is completely different.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on version 1.7.4

I solved the problem by commenting the following line in the file

> \src\PrestaShopBundle\Controller\Admin\ModuleController.php

```
$filters = new AddonListFilter();
 $filters->setType(AddonListFilterType::MODULE | AddonListFilterType::SERVICE);
 //    ->removeStatus(AddonListFilterStatus::UNINSTALLED);
 $installedProducts = $moduleRepository->getFilteredList($filters);
```

I don't know why we can't see the uninstalled module

Comment: go in the Selection tab, not the installed modules

Answer (score 3):

Just go to module catalog instead of Modules Manager, and you will find your custom modules.